# Issue:When use ui-bootstrap modal ,browser hangs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **ui-bootstrap modal** to handle a **modal** and I want to show the modal pop-up when redirected to the state.

Actually my code is:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
  .controller('topicsCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $uibModal, getCandidateInterviewListService, searchBoxService, candidateRatingService) {
    debugger;
    $scope.oCandidateDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oCandidateDetails'));
    console.log($scope.oCandidateDetails);
    $scope.myValue = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.oCandidateDetails.aDetails, function(value, key) {
      if (value.name == $scope.oCandidateDetails.name) {
        $scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://localhost:4000/" + value.filepath);
        $scope.oJdDetails = value.club[0].jdDetails;
      }
    });
    $scope.aAskedQuestions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('askedQuestions')).askedQues;
    $scope.fngetQList = function(topics, index) {
      debugger;
      $scope.displayQList = true;
      $scope.sTopics = topics;
      $scope.index = index;
      getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList(topics).then(function(response) {
        $scope.aQuestionList = response;
        console.log($scope.aQuestionList);
      });
    };
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
    <a class="col-xs-6">Start Interview</a>
    <a class="col-xs-6">View Page</a>
</div>
```

I'm using the same controller for modal also, but when the page is loading the browser is getting hanged.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should write separate controller for modal and you can try comment for loop to test performance. Last time I met the same problem and I found the problem from the loop.

Comment: You may get into infinite loop so to resolve this issue you should use different controller and html for modal.

Answer (score 0):

Browser hang means you ended up in an infinite loop of one sort or another.  This can happen when using angular sometimes because of using the server side redirects to the index.html.  If a template path doesn't get loaded and it ends up loading the index.html then it can end up in an infinite recursion of loading the index over and over (the requested path won't be for the index.html but the contents being returned will be that file's contents).  Be sure your template url is correct or try using an inline template: 'just testing' to see if that's the issue in general.